# Cannot Detach from process using mdbg

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, mdbg

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367966/how-to-intercept-debugging-information-debugview-style-in-c) I now have code that can attach to a process using the Mdbg API.

The problem is that I can't detach from the process if I need to. When I call 
**mgProcess.Detach().WaitOne();** ( where mgProcess is a MDbgProcess created from an MDbgEngine object ) I get the following error message:

```
 Process not synchronized. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131302)
     at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.NativeApi.ICorDebugController.Detach()
     at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.CorController.Detach() in C:\mdbg\src\debugger\corapi\Controller.cs:line 89
     at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.MdbgEngine.MDbgProcess.Detach() in C:\mdbg\src\debugger\mdbgeng\Process.cs:line 716
```

If I just try to call **mgProcess.Detach()** or **mgProcess.CorProcess.Detach()** I get the same result.

Does anyone know the correct way to detach an Mdbg process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It transpires that Mdbg will not allow you to do anything [while the debugee is running](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/03/22/att-macros.aspx).

```
  MgProcess.CorProcess.Stop(0);
  MgProcess.Detach();
```

Appears to be the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
proc.AsyncStop();
proc.Detach();
```

or

```
Proc.CorProcess.Stop(0);  
Proc.Detach();
```